# Pandas DataFrame filling in a column incorrectly -- Strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get different results in a for loop from `print` and `df.at`. Can this be explained?

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A', []], ['B', []], ['C', []], ['D', []]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Act', 'PreviousActs'])

actssofar = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
 actssofar.append(row['Act'])
 print (i, actssofar)
 df.at[i,'PreviousActs'] = actssofar
```

Now, the output of the `print` function in the for loop is this:

```
0 ['A']
1 ['A', 'B']
2 ['A', 'B', 'C']
3 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

But the output of the dataframe is this:

| Acts | PreviousActs |
| --- | --- |
| A | A, B, C, D |
| B | A, B, C, D |
| C | A, B, C, D |
| D | A, B, C, D |

Logically, shouldn't it show the same step-by-step appending behavior as the print function, since we are filling the dataframe with the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that, when the loop finishes, your dataframe contains `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` for all rows.This happens because you are passing the list as "reference", which means all rows are storing the same list. You should add a `list()` call to create a new list everytime you assign it to the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A', []], ['B', []], ['C', []], ['D', []]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Act', 'PreviousActs'])

actssofar = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
 actssofar.append(row['Act'])
 print (i, actssofar)
 df.at[i,'PreviousActs'] = list(actssofar)
```

Updated answer that makes use of mutability and is more memory efficient as it only creates one list.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A', []], ['B', []], ['C', []], ['D', []]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Act', 'PreviousActs'])

actssofar = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
 actssofar.append(row['Act'])
 print (i, actssofar)
 df.at[i,'PreviousActs'] = actssofar[:i+1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Considering that this is happening in the loop, and the value of `actssofar` is changing every time, shouldn't the "reference" be the same as the "value"? If I want to delve into this topic, what should I search?

Comment: In Python, lists are considered "containers" this is, objects that contain data in some structured way (like tuples, dicts and sets). Also, lists are mutable objects, which means that the values that the list holds are allowed to change during the execution time. If you look at your code you can see that everytime you assign the list to the DataFrame, you are passing the same "container" but not the values that are contained within it. By using `list()`you are making a "copy" of the container that you never modify again. You should look into Python containers and mutability of objects.

Comment: Note that you can also make great use of the mutability of objects! There's a reason objects are mutable. It allows you to pass a vast amount of data to a function while under the hood, Python is just passing a tiny pointer. But you also have to keep track of where you are passing that reference, because as soon as you start writing to it, you can get in trouble.

Comment: Of course! mutability can be very useful if used right. I updated my answer to show a solution that uses mutability.

Comment: Thanks to you both, this is Indeed well explained.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the list before putting it in the DataFrame. It's a mutable object, and what you are currently storing in the DataFrame is a *reference* to the original list, not a copy of it. Every element in the PreviousActs column is the same list.